# How to replace content of a popup window with an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, popup

I am at loss to understand how popup windows´ DOM-trees and their manipulation from opener window work. What is the proper way to implement what I am trying to do (described below)?

I have one normal browser window where JavaScript function gathers selected elements and creates POST data string from them.
I then open a popup window with placeholder content, bind a function to window.ready that does the AJAX request and then try to replace the HTML in popup window with AJAX results.

In code this is *done in JavaScript run on the opener window:*.

```
function showMessages(queryParams, width, height) {
    var mailWindow = window.open('html/blankwithdoctype.html', 'foo', 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height='+height+',width='+width);
    var params = queryParams.substring(1);
    $(mailWindow.document).ready(function() {
        doPostRequest(params, mailWindow);
    });
    return mailWindow;
}

function doPostRequest(queryParams, mailWindow) {
    function callback(data, textStatus) {
        var mv = mailWindow;
        $(mv.document).find("html").html(data);
    };
    $.post('MailFile.do', queryParams, callback);
}
```

When breaking at `$(mv.document).find("html").html(data);` with Chrome developer tools or Firefox+FireBug, I notice that temporarily the result is shown but after the JQuery call stack is unwound (after  `$.post('MailFile.do', queryParams, callback);`) the original blank page is yet again shown.

Without a debugger, I notice that rendering of the result page is atleast started but it is quickly replaced with the original placeholder page.

Something funny is definitely going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the jQuery library is not loaded in the popup window. Then, when the code that follows the ready event in the popup window is executed, the `$` function is unknown, causing the error. I might be wrong though, I have never used `ready()` in a cross-window fashion (and always on `document`, not on `window)`.

EDIT: What you could also do (instead of including jQuery in the opened window) is replace every `$` in the opened window with `window.opener.$`. But that's rather ugly, now, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: Not loading the jQuery library is not the source of problems here. My original question did not explain that all this manipulation is done in the opener window so lack of JQuery in the opened window should not be a problem.

Comment: I was aware of that. However, the anonymous function that you pass to `ready()` of the opened window is executed in the global context of the opened window, if I am not mistaken. That's why I thought there might be a visibility problem. Have you actually tried it? Could be that `$` is visible due to closure, though, I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was looking for a way around this problem myself. I'm guessing the browser prevents access to modifying the DOM of a child window for security reasons. (I'm wishing it gave some sort of error, but I never got one)

In any case, I didn't need an already existing page to open, my application did require a separate popup though to accommodate multiple screens.

After opening up the popup with `window.open(null, null, "...options...")`, I simply called `document.write("...FULL HTML FOR POPUP...")` and built the entire popup essentially from scratch. From that point, I had access to any DOM operations I wanted to perform from the parent window.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
// using null for the URL (defaults to about:blank in some browsers)
// using null for the Window Name (allowed me to have multiple popups)
var popup = window.open(null, null, "width=600,height=600");

// overwrite the entire document with our own HTML
popup.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>');

// Using jQuery for DOM manipulation here
var $popup = $("body", popup.document);
```

I only really tested this in Chrome and Firefox, unfortunately. Also, even setting the  tag never changed the title of the popup window. It's not a perfect solution, but it worked in my situation.